# Implement a password list for splitted .rar archives extraction from different folder locations

Tags: batch-file

I use a script to extract splitted archives in multiple folders.
For example

```
folder root
|
|
+---folder1
|      |
|      |_a.part1.rar
|      |_a.part2.rar
|
|
+---folder2
|      |
|      |_b.part01.rar
|      |_b.part02.rar
|....
```

My problem is to understand how to implement a password list because some archives need a password to extract, for example how can I implement a password list like (some passwords include special characters like @?!...

```
password1
password2
password3
....
```

Maybe is needed a powershell equivalent script to manage Unicode characters for password?

However this is my script

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=Z:\## 2021\Film\by downloaditaly\1080p"
set "LogExtract=%SourceFolder%\ExtractionLog.txt"
set "LogError=%SourceFolder%\ErrorLog.txt"
set "ArchiveExtracted="

del /Q "%LogExtract%" "%LogError%" 2>nul

for /D %%I in ("%SourceFolder%\*") do (
    if /I not "%%~nxI" == "done" (
        for %%J in ("%%I\*.rar" "%%I\*.zip") do (
            if exist "%%J" (
                echo Extracting "%%J" ...
                "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -cfg- -ibck -logpfu="%LogExtract%" -o+ -y -- "%%J" "%%I\"
                if errorlevel 1 (
                    set "ArchiveFile=%%J"
                    >>"%LogError%" call echo Error %%ErrorLevel%% on extracting "%%ArchiveFile%%"
                ) else (
                    set "#%%~nxI=%%I"
                    set "ArchiveExtracted=1"
                    echo %%~nJ| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R "\.part[0123456789][0123456789]*$" >nul
                    if errorlevel 1 ( del /F "%%J" ) else for %%# in ("%%~nJ") do del /F /Q "%%I\%%~n#.part*%%~xJ"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)



endlocal
```